# Define a scope for certain iOS SDK versions in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

is there a way to define a block scope (where I can define structs or classes) which is valid only for certain iOS sdk versions?
Suppose I want to provide a custom implementation for a class which is defined only for iOS 10; my implementation should work only for iOS 9 or lower.
I know there is #available statement and I can out my scope inside the else condition but... when I try to put it in a swift file compiler say to me I cannot use #available in top level scope.
What it means?
Can't I define a scope with classes and structs at top level? How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using @available instead of #available.

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
```

Comment: available works as "this is available since 10.0" while I should define something which is valid with a version < 10. Moreover available does not work with an entire scope but only for functions.

Comment: By entire scope, you mean entire class?

Comment: Yeah I should define a class and a struct inside this scope (even separately)

Comment: @available should work for class, structs, enums. Do you see any compilation issues?